# Azure B2C: Querying AAD using a custom claim?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Note that this ties with a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66327807/azure-b2c-checking-if-another-claim-exists-during-local-account-creation), but I've gain a bit of a better understanding of Azure Active Directory (AAD) with custom policies.

Is it possible to query AAD by using a custom claim?  For example, I want to use a claim called organizationName (extension_organizationName) to check whether it's already defined.  If it was already defined, then I don't want to create the account.

Here's the claim provider that I wrote up to determine this:

```xml
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Azure Active Directory</DisplayName>
        <TechnicalProfiles>
        <!--Demo: This technical profile tries to find a local account with provided email address-->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadOrganization-NoError">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">false</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_organizationName" Required="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <!-- Required claims -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tempOrganization"/>
          </OutputClaims>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
```

However, I got the same validation error that I've hit previously, but for a different reason:

> Unable to validate the information provided.

If I can't query for an organization, then how else can I check if a custom claim value already exists inside AAD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Abhishek stated you can not query AAD B2C using your custom `extension_organizationName` claim. An alternative solution would be to check if the organization claim is already present in the AAD by calling a [custom REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-rest-api-intro), which queries the AAD via the Graph API (similar to the way it is described [in this blogpost](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/working-with-custom-attributes-in-azure-ad-b2c-custom-policies-fae1454b12bf)).

Answer (score 1):

You can not query Azure AD using random claims. You can query using only unique claims. From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-technical-profile#inputclaims

> To read, update, or delete an existing user account, the input claim
> is a key that uniquely identifies the account in Azure AD directory.
> For example, objectId, userPrincipalName, signInNames.emailAddress,
> signInNames.userName, or alternativeSecurityId.

If your scenario is to have organization name as unique, you can consider suffixing it in user principal name. A better explanation of scenario might help in answer.

Comment: The organization name is only unique for the admin who creates an organizational account.  Users who are invited by admin automatically share the same organization name

Comment: You can keep this list of already created organizations in your database as well, instead of AzureAd. Then using RestAPI you can block or allow a registration. It will be faster.

Comment: True.  I'll go with that solution.  Thanks