# Looking up users in AAD B2C using extension attributes or unusual standard attributes

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66345321/azure-b2c-querying-aad-using-a-custom-claim?rq=1). I need to query AAD B2C to lookup a user using an employeeID which, for reasons related to what fields our account provisioning solution can deal with, is currently stored in the telephoneNumber field.

I have created an Azure Active Directory TechnicalProfile which specifies the telephone number as the InputClaim:

```
 <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingEmployeeId">
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
        <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
        <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">An account could not be found for the provided ID.</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="telephoneNumber" PartnerClaimType="employeeId" Required="true" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.phoneNumber" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="telephoneNumber" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

However, when compiling this policy I get the error:

```
"Input Claim 'telephoneNumber' is not supported in Azure Active Directory Provider technical profile 'AAD-UserReadUsingEmployeeId'"
```

I understand from the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-profile-attributes) that telephoneNumber can only be used as persistentClaim or OutputClaim... so I suppose I may be hitting that limitation. I thought I could wiggle out of this by querying AAD B2C using an extension attribute instead, but there I get confused:

- The answers to the question I linked to earlier state that you can't query AAD B2C through some random attribute, because the attribute needs to be unique
- The FIDO2 sample policy [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/fido2/policy/FIDOExtensions.xml) *does* use an extension attribute to query AAD B2C and lookup a user, so it would appear to be possible in some conditions.

So, would I be correct in understanding that

- You *can* use any extension attribute to lookup a user in AAD B2C, and it's on you to ensure that the attribute values are unique
- You *can't* use most of the standard attributes (such as telephoneNumber) to look up users

Or is there something obvious I'm overlooking in the way I've configured the TechnicalProfile ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are correct:

- You can use any extension attribute to lookup a user in AAD B2C, and
  it's on you to ensure that the attribute values are unique
- You can't use most of the standard attributes (such as telephoneNumber) to look up users

Comment: Thanks Alfredo. Is there any reason for this behaviour? If you can lookup by extension attributes, I don't see what prevents B2C from doing the same with standard attributes?